# fabricjs removing objects (line) from canvas but not all objects are getting removed

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am relatively new to fabricjs.
I am creating a grid on the canvas with fabricjs(1.7.11),

What I am trying to achieve:

basically, when I click a button a grid is created and when I click another button I want to delete the grid ( the grid is made of fabricjs lines) but for some reason, not all lines are getting removed.

function to create the grid

```
var grid = 30;
var cWidth = canvas.getWidth();

function CanvasGrid(){
    for(var i = 0; i < (cWidth / grid); i++){
        canvas.add(new fabric.Line([i * grid, 0, i * grid, cWidth], {
            stroke: '#ccc',
            selectable: false
        }));

        canvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, i * grid, cWidth, i * grid], {
            stroke: '#ccc',
            selectable: false
        }));
    }
}
```

Created grid on canvas:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYnFR.jpg

function to delete grid:

```
function RemoveGrid(){
    var objects = canvas.getObjects('line');
    for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
        canvas.item(i).remove();        
    }   
    RenderCanvas();
}
```

Result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0eBu.jpg

I want to remove the rest of the lines. Any help much appreciated.

Thank you.

edit: 
I tried this solution but I have to keep clicking on the button till all lines are removed.

```
function RemoveGrid(){
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj){
        if(obj.type === 'line'){
            obj.remove();
        }
    });

    RenderCanvas();
}
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the following function to remove all the grids ...

```
function RemoveGrid() {
    var objects = canvas.getObjects('line');
    for (let i in objects) {
        canvas.remove(objects[i]);
    }
    RenderCanvas();
}
```

---

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var grid = 30;
var cWidth = canvas.getWidth();

// add grid
function CanvasGrid() {
    for (var i = 0; i < (cWidth / grid); i++) {
        canvas.add(new fabric.Line([i * grid, 0, i * grid, cWidth], {
            stroke: '#ccc',
            selectable: false
        }));
        canvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, i * grid, cWidth, i * grid], {
            stroke: '#ccc',
            selectable: false
        }));
    }
}

// remove grid
function RemoveGrid() {
    var objects = canvas.getObjects('line');
    for (let i in objects) {
        canvas.remove(objects[i]);
    }
    RenderCanvas();
}
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid #999}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="CanvasGrid()">Add Grid</button>
<button onclick="RemoveGrid()">Remove Grid</button>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: You are a star. Thank you.

Comment: @GRUNT: it is taking little bit time, is there any way to make it more faster?